# How to present popover ArrowDirections properly in iOS 9 swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, popover

I have been trying to find out that how can fix the problem.

On this line`popover.permittedArrowDirections = ( .Up | .Down )` It says "Type of expression is ambiquous without more context."

Here's the code example:

```
if let popover = alert.popoverPresentationController
        {
        popover.sourceView = imageView
        popover.sourceRect = imageView.bounds
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = ( .Up | .Down )
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use below code:

```
popover.permittedArrowDirections = [ .Up, .Down ]
```